# Separating emails by commas in Outlook 2016 Mac

Tags: email, ms-office

How can I get Outlook 2016 for Mac to allow separating entered email addresses by commas instead of semicolons?

[I have found directions for how to do this on Windows](https://www.lifewire.com/commas-to-separate-email-recipients-1173680), but I have not been able to find a corresponding option on Outlook for Mac- it just insists on only recognizing semicolons.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, you can't. I had this problem last year with one of my personal clients who wanted to use Outlook 2016 for his email instead of the Apple Mail app. There was no way that I could find to make Outlook switch from semi-colons to commas. I did a fair amount of research then (and did some additional research just now) but came up empty.

In the end, my client went back to Apple Mail.

Sorry I have nothing definitive.